# Most efficient way to normalize values in a Counter values in a dict<key, counter> against all keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, normalization

Given a dictionary like this:

```
{

'key1': Counter({a:1, b:1}),
'key2': Counter({c:10, d:20})
}
```

What I want, is a dictionary with normalized scores against each key -

```
{

'key1':{a:0.5, b:0.5},
'key2':{c:0.33, d:0.67}
}
```

What would be an efficient way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple for loop to get the total and then to divide by the total?

Comment: Nothing, per say. Could use 2 loops, but is there a vectorized-like way to do this? @DanielMesejo

Comment: Vectorized as in numpy or pandas, I don't think there is one

Comment: @RahulDev "vectorized"? No, vanilla Python data structures do not support vectorization. In any case, that wouldn't make your code more algorithmically efficient.

Comment: As an aside, *please post valid Python source code in your examples*.